# Tokenizing a String for Multiple Types

Tags: c++, templates, types, tokenize

I had gotten used to working with a function, in C++, that parses a string/buffer, delimited by a specific character, and would assign one of these tokens to a value passed in by reference, and returning the rest of the buffer/string.  My memory is a little bit faulty in how it worked however, and I am having a bit of difficulty trying to recreate it.

I was wondering if it was possible to do this through a clever use of template functions, as I am not entirely familiar with the usage of template functions.

What I am aiming for is something along the lines of

```
// assume buffer is a string, delimited by some character, say '^'
// in this particular scenario: 5^3.14^test^
TokenAssignment( buffer, testInt );
TokenAssignment( buffer, testFloat );
TokenAssignment( buffer, testString );

template<class Token>
void TokenAssignment(std::string& buffer, Token& tokenToBeAssigned)
{
    std::string::size_type offset = buffer.find_first_of ('^');

    /* Logic here assigns token to the value in the string regardless of type. */

    // move the buffer on
    buffer = buffer.substr(offset+1);
}

// so the three calls above would have
// testInt = 5
// testFloat = 3.14f
// testString = "test"
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and you're more than halfway there. Are you familiar with [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream)?

Comment: I am not particularly familiar with it.

I do recall seeing #include <sstream> some time ago.  Not sure if that is the same thing.

I suppose the difficulty I'm finding is getting the value in the string to assign properly without having to check the type of the token (and then changing the behavior to use atoi or atof).

Trying to figure out if template specialization is what I should be aiming for, however that seems like i am just rewriting the function.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the first part down, splitting the string into smaller strings ("5", "3.14", "test").

To assign those values to variables of other types (e.g. "3.14" => `3.14`), `stringstream` is very handy:

```
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
void scanString(std::string str, T &x)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << str;
  ss >> x;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Do you know how it works "underneath the hood"?
I think that is what I've been trying to implement. (Looking it up right now, it looks like it has something to do with operator overloading)

Comment: @user2788618: [shrug] It's derived from `iostream`, and you can put things in and take them out as different types. That's about as deep under the hood as I care to go.